# "Featured on Meta" section sometimes (but not always) shows symbols as HTML entities

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag, html-entities

This appears to have broken sometime today and is currently broken on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  There's been [no change to the post's title in that time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/410831/revisions).

How it looked yesterday:

[image: "Featured on Meta" section showing "Don't be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties"]

How it looks today:

[image: "Featured on Meta" section showing "Don&#39;t be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties"]

The same applies today, in the featured post [Stack Exchange Q&A access will not be restricted in Russia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376743/stack-exchange-qampa-access-will-not-be-restricted-in-russia): the "Q&A" sometimes, but not always, shows up as "Q&amp;A".

Comment: And ...it's mysteriously fixed itself, with no change to the question.  I can no longer reproduce.  I originally tested this in a private window with no userscripts as well, just in case, so it's not that.

Comment: [At least one other user also saw this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52863239#52863239), so it's not just me, but they cannot reproduce anymore either.

Comment: I also saw this (I think 2 days ago) but it fixed in a few minutes only. Strange.

Comment: And now it's happening again!

Comment: And now it's working correctly again.

Comment: Maybe they play "Catch the Apostrophe" game.