# A gesture of solidarity with Ukraine

Tags: feature-request

Changing the `+10` badge to the Ukrainian colours would be a simple  gesture of solidarity with Ukraine and would act as a constant reminder across the world that Ukraine is fighting for their freedom every second.

[image]

Comment: The contrast ratio of the [actual colors of the flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ukraine) is rather small for use in normal text, at 4.91:1. While I do stand in solidarity with Ukraine (see my username), I'm also an advocate for higher contrast ratios.

Comment: if you didn't see it, I really like this idea: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376775/1154146

Comment: Are other large tech companies doing similar things in "gestures of solidarity?" Why do you think this is something StackExchange needs to do?

Comment: @scohe001 "Are other large tech companies doing similar things" - They're doing much more. Microsoft and Apple have both stopped selling to Russia.

Comment: A full banner would be clearer than either this or icon-changing suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm not in favor of this, as it decreases legibility, but feel free to do it yourself with a userstyle manager like [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/):

```
.top-bar .indicator-badge._positive {
  background-color: #0057b7;
  color: #ffd700;
}
```

[image]

(colors taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ukraine))

Comment: The point is for it to be a community-wide gesture, surely?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a lovely idea.

It may be a slightly lower contrast, but the score notification is already given secondary importance in the site experience (because it doesn't appear when the net score difference from last notification is negative), so that doesn't seem a primary concern.