# Is Stack Exchange blocked in/by Russia?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, firewall

[Stack Exchange recently announced that they are not blocking Russia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376743/stack-exchange-qa-access-will-not-be-restricted-in-russia). However, is the converse also true—that Russia is not blocking Stack Exchange?
<sub>(I'm asking this because if Russia is not blocking the Stack Exchange network, then that means we could spread information to Russians via, e.g., a thread called "Info on Ukraine")</sub>

So, how can I find out whether Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange network, more generally) is blocked in Russia?

Comment: What do you mean by "thread" in that context?

Comment: I mean someone "asking a question" on Ukraine and everyone puts a copy of news in the answer.

Comment: Still here, nothing's blocked. None of those who make decisions about blocking websites in my country even knows what the Stack Exchange network is, believe me (I am not sure they know what a *network* is in the first place, but that's another topic). Every blocked site is included in a [publicly available list](https://eais.rkn.gov.ru/)

Comment: *I mean someone "asking a question" on Ukraine and everyone puts a copy of news in the answer* - not really what the SE network is for though, is it? New outlets already publish info on how to install VPNs/bypasses so those inclined can get info from original sources without it having come though someone pasting/editing it via some forum. Trust in information terms is usually by establishing direct communication with a regarded source, rather than going via an "anyone can edit" intermediary

Comment: You ask two things here, which is reason to close the question. Please focus on one question at a time, you can also post a new question. Since you already have answers, better leave the "Is Stack Exchange blocked in/by Russia?" here, and ask about "spread information to Russians" in a new discussion.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar He's not asking how to spread information, or if we _should_. He's just using it to explain why he's asking if SE is blocked.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's not how I read this. It's just noise, if OP doesn't mean to ask to add such a thing.

Comment: _"We could do X"_ is just a statement justifying this question. He's not asking _how_, and he's not asking if we _should_. This feels like you're just digging for a close-reason... Keep in mind that this question was migrated here from SO, and in that process re-opened.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Before the edit, it was more apparent that I stated (approximately): Is it prohibited, because if not we could do this and that. Nevertheless, I do not blame the editor for revising my question, because besides that unclarity my question ended up more concise. Slava Ukraini!

Comment: There, edited it so there can be no doubt about what this question is asking.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks, but sadly others voted to close for different reason, I can't see which exactly. :/

Comment: “Not about SE”… which is silly.

Comment: Funny to see how people care about a simple question and worry about it not being "about SE" (bull feces) when @Cerbrus and OlegWalteriswithUkraine have already answered it. But thanks for the support and answers everyone :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, Russia hasn't blocked Stack Overflow, [nor has SE blocked Russian traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376743/stack-exchange-qa-access-will-not-be-restricted-in-russia).

As for finding out what's blocked from where, I suppose you could set up a VPN that's based in Russia and try for yourself.

---

A quick search resulted in this website, that can check if a site is blocked from Russia:

https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockedinrussia/

It says Stack Overflow is still accessible from Vladivostok

Comment: `I suppose you could set up a VPN that's based in Russia and try for yourself.` - if you do this, make sure to do it in a sandbox; see the [node-ipc drama](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-NODEIPC-2426370).

Answer (score 9):

No, Russia has not blocked access to the Stack Exchange network (it does not seem there are plans to either - the network is neither a media outlet nor has it taken any actions that would make the authorities to want it).

At the time of this writing, the post should be proof enough that it has not, but if one is curious enough, they can check the publicly available [list of resources](https://eais.rkn.gov.ru/) blocked in Russia which is maintained by the Federal Service for Supervision in the Sphere of Telecom, Information Technologies and Mass Communications ("better" known as RosKomNadzor).

Comment: FSSSTITMC doesn't quite roll off of the tongue... _"Fsss Tit MC"_ is kinda funny tho.